# How to use IConfig from pg-promise typescript?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, pg-promise

How can i use Interfaces defined in pg-promise typescript module in my code.
Eg: I want to mention configuration object with type 'IConfig'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) uses type [IConfig](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/typescript/pg-promise.d.ts) implicitly (for internal declaration only).

This means you don't need to use the type explicitly, you can set up your own custom object, without any specific type, and then pass it in when creating the database object:

```
var config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    /// etc.
};

var db = pgp(config);
```

Alternatively, if you want the benefit of strict typing, you can use it in-line, in which case the type will be enforced by the TypeScript:

```
var db = pgp({
    host: 'localhost',
    /// etc.
});
```

**UPDATE**

Following this, TypeScript for [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) has been updated to export type `IConfig`.

See [v.5.1.4 release notes](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.5.1.4).

Comment: Why are you not exporting interfaces in pg-promise?

Comment: The library exports the interfaces that mirror the library's protocol, plus the ones the are required because of the TypeScripts specific. `IConfig` isn't any of those.

Comment: @Fahad I have checked in [an update](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/commit/58dc975ab2358af74a264b61c024b06b721e0dd7) to export `IConfig` ;)